# I am trying to validate my textfield without alert function in javascript but it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

This function is for validation.  It prints am error if it's empty and shows either red or green along with an OK msg beside the text box.

**JavaScript**

```
 function validatebox()
 {
     var fn = document.geElementById("fn").value;
     if (fn==null || fn=="")
     {
         document.geElementById("error_fn").innerHTML="please fill your first name";
         document.geElementById("error_fn").style.color="red";
     }
     else
     {
         document.geElementById("error_fn").innerHTML="OK";
         document.geElementById("error_fn").style.color="green";
     }
```

I am trying to display the error message beside the text box but its not working.

**HTML**

```
 <form  name="signup" action="singup_i" method="post">
   First name:
   <input type="text" id="fn" onblur="validatebox()" name="fn"  size="15"/> 
   <label id="error_fn"></label>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"> <input type="reset" value="reset">
 </from>
```

Answer (score 7):

Three problems:

1. It's `getElementById` (note the `t`), not `geElementById`.
2. You're missing the ending `}` on your function.
3. Your closing tag for the form is `</from>`, not `</form>`

Your browser was probably telling you about at least the first two: In all modern browsers, there's a full set of development/debugging tools. For IE and Chrome (at least), just press F12. For others, look in the menus.

Fix those and it works: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ucezij/3) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ucezij/3/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form  name="signup" action="singup_i" method="post">
First name:<input type="text" id="fn" onblur="validatebox()" name="fn"  size="15"/> 
              <label id="error_fn"></label>
         <input type="submit" value="submit"> <input type="reset" value="reset">
</from>
<script>
function validatebox() {

    var fn = document.getElementById("fn").value;
    if (fn == null || fn == "") {
        document.getElementById("error_fn").innerHTML = "please fill your first name";
        document.getElementById("error_fn").style.color = "red";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error_fn").innerHTML = "OK";
        document.getElementById("error_fn").style.color = "green";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I've reformatted the function code a bit, so it's easier to see the blocks (and therefore see the ending `}`).

But can I suggest not looking up the `error_fn` repeatedly, and not using a `label` element for something other than labelling a field: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ucezij/4) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ucezij/4/edit)

```
<form  name="signup" action="singup_i" method="post">
 First name:<input type="text" id="fn" onblur="validatebox()" name="fn"  size="15"/> 
               <span id="error_fn"></span>
          <input type="submit" value="submit"> <input type="reset" value="reset">
</form>
<script>
function validatebox() {

    var fn = document.getElementById("fn").value;
    var err = document.getElementById("error_fn");
    if (fn == null || fn == "") {
        err.innerHTML = "please fill your first name";
        err.style.color = "red";
    }
    else {
        err.innerHTML = "OK";
        err.style.color = "green";
    }
}
</script>
```

Finally, `fn` will never be `null`, because the `value` property of a text field will never be `null`; it's always a string. The string may be blank. In this case, the easiest test would just be `if (!fn) { /* missing */ } else { /* present */}`, which will test `fn` to see if it's `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `false`, or `NaN` (of which, it can only be `""`, because again `value` is always a string). Of course, `" "` (a space) would get past that.

Comment: also `from` !== `form`

Comment: It might be good to handle the validation on "submit" instead of (or in addition to) when the input is changed.

Comment: Nice answer to beginner :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, in addition at least.

Answer (score 0):

Many errors:

---

getElementbyId not geElementbyId
form not from
End your input with /

Comment: *"End your input with /"* Well, he did once, and he didn't once. Unless the page is XHTML (in which case it has bigger issues), it doesn't matter. In HTML (rather than XHTML), the `/` before `>` is tolerated, not required.

Comment: Errors occurs at editing so here comes a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WKwnW/